# Spark dataframe grouping, sorting, and selecting top rows for a set of columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.0. I have a Spark dataframe with following columns:

```
| user_id | description | fName | weight |
```

What I would like to do is to select top 10 and bottom 10 rows (based on the value of column weight, which is of datatype Double) per user. How do I do that using Spark SQL or dataframe operations?

For example. for simplicity I am only selecting top 2 rows (based on weight) per user. I would like to sort the o/p on the value of the absolute weight.

```
u1  desc1 f1  -0.20
u1  desc1 f1  +0.20
u2  desc1 f1  0.80
u2  desc1 f1  -0.60
u1  desc1 f1  1.10
u1  desc1 f1  6.40
u2  desc1 f1  0.05
u1  desc1 f1  -3.20
u2  desc1 f1  0.50
u2  desc1 f1  -0.70
u2  desc1 f1  -0.80
```

Here is the desired o/p:

```
u1  desc1 f1  6.40
u1  desc1 f1  -3.20
u1  desc1 f1  1.10
u1  desc1 f1  -0.20
u2  desc1 f1  0.80
u2  desc1 f1  -0.80
u2  desc1 f1  -0.70
u2  desc1 f1  0.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions with `row_number`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"user_id")
val rankAsc = row_number().over(w.orderBy($"weight")).alias("rank_asc")
val rankDesc = row_number().over(w.orderBy($"weight".desc)).alias("rank_desc")

df.select($"*", rankAsc, rankDesc).filter($"rank_asc" <= 2 || $"rank_desc" <= 2)
```

In Spark 1.5.0 you can use `rowNumber` instead of `row_number`.

Comment: I think row_number is not included with Spark 1.5. I get this error: scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
<console>:29: error: value row_number is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions
       import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

Comment: You're right, but solution is the same even though function name differs (`rowNumber`).

Comment: How are the row numbers, computed separately, associated with the dataset df records?

Comment: @SumitKumarGhosh I am not sure if I follow. Do you ask about `rankAsc` / `rankDesc`? There is no computation there. These are only SQL expressions which are used to generate execution plan for `filter`.